# C# WPF) how to minimize a parent window after child modal window is showed by showdialog()?

Tags: c#, wpf, modal-dialog, window, minimize

I've searched some posts on stackoverflow and some discussion concluded as there's no way to do this as it's standard behavior of WPF modal Window.

Isn't there really a solution to minimize(control) the parent Window from a modal child Window?

Anybody who hacked or knows a roundtrip ?

Your excellent ideas will be highly appreciated always.

Thank you !

Comment: Did you try passing a reference to parent dialog and `parent.WindowState = WindowState.Minimized` ?

Comment: Dear Emperor, Many thanks for your precious time and comment !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the reference of your Window via application window collection. This is an example of minimizing the MainWindow which is in my example the parent window:

```
    private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Window win in Application.Current.Windows.OfType<MainWindow>())
        {
            var mainWin = ((MainWindow)win);
            mainWin.WindowState = mainWin.WindowState == WindowState.Minimized ? WindowState.Normal : WindowState.Minimized;
        }
    }
```

You can just set the window state to minimized.

If you want to get rid of the window just use `.Hide();` and to show it agian `.Show();`.

Comment: In this scenario once the parent window is minimized it cannot be recovered

Comment: When you use `.Hide();` => Yes, but it can be showed again in Closed event via `.Show();`. Thats why I wrote you can use WindowState. With that, it is not gone.

Comment: Oh..Thank you so much ! Honestly, I didn't expect some positive solution as some people concluded without a solution. But, this works really fine. You are one of good teachers ! Hope your great achievements !

Comment: Dear Vivek, Many thanks for your precious time and comment !

Comment: I tried to help..but @SebastianSchulz seized the day :)

Comment: How about trying this: Application.Current.MainWindow.Minimize();