# WPF: About modal window and modeless window, how to access modeless window after show modal window?

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to emulate a console window for wpf debug.

So I did the following:
Main window open the console window using Show();
Main window open another MyWindow using ShowDialog();
When using MyWindow, I can't access my console window.

How to solve this?

Comment: Seems this might help. Please try as this is controlling a parent Window from modal child Window. If parent Window opens child Window through showdialog(), the child Window takes the control as you know well. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36976769/c-sharp-wpf-how-to-minimize-a-parent-window-after-child-modal-window-is-showed

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, once you use ShowDialog(), the user can no longer interact with any other already open Window. If you want to switch between 2 windows, you cannot use ShowDialog().

However, you could open a new Console Window from MyWindow.