# How to make window modal to child window but not parent window

Tags: c#, wpf

My application has a couple layers:

It has the mainWindow with which the user may start several independent sub-processes.

Some of these sub-process windows open modal windows.
My problem is that I want these modal windows to disable only the direct parent window and not the mainWindow (Grandparent window). the users should still be able to access any of the other independent sub-processes.

Is this possible, and how can it be done?

Comment: As just quick comment, how about making the directparentWindow.IsEnabled=false ?  You can refer to this link to control Windows. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36976769/c-sharp-wpf-how-to-minimize-a-parent-window-after-child-modal-window-is-showed

Comment: Have you tried to use [`Window.Owner`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.window.owner%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property of modal window?

Comment: @Sam I have explored with the Window.Owner, The problems seems to be that the disable seems to travel up the chain and all parent, grandparent, and cousin windows lock up. I only want the parent window to lock.